# Adaptive card with Luis intent

Tags: adaptive-cards

this approach was working for me nicely until last month. But now i am getting error msg that my bot code is havin an issue. Is there any changes to it recently. Here is my code>

```
protected override Task<string> GetLuisQueryTextAsync(IDialogContext context, IMessageActivity message)
        {
            if (message.Value != null)
            {
                dynamic value = message.Value;
                // assuming your DataJson has a type property like :
                // DataJson = "{ \"Type\": \"Curse\" }" 
                string submitType = value.x.ToString();
                return Task.FromResult(submitType);

            }
            else
            {
                // no Adaptive Card value, let's call the base
                return base.GetLuisQueryTextAsync(context, message);
            }

        }
```

Datajson> "x":"introduction"

Answer (score 0):

When you debug into this method, which line does the error occur?
There are a number of places in the method that 'could' be potential problems.
Is 'message' null?
Are you sure message.Value is a properly formed json string? 
Does the properly formatted json string actuall contain 'x'?

Let us know where in the method the error is occurring and what the exception is.